# Android Boot Debug : Init ends up in OnBootPhase_XXX loop ( Android-13 on Qemu / Virtual Platform )

Tags: qemu, android-debug, android-13, android-debugging, fvp

I am new to Android bringup, Kernel boot seems successful and we arrive at console prompt but beyond that, logcat does not reveal what might be holding back Android-13 boot.

In terms of Software, we have a setup to build Android-12 succesfully for our specific lunch menu & device spec (arm64 based). For Android-13 we have used the same setup and pointed to the following source branches.

ANDROID_BRANCH=android-13.0.0_r18
KERNEL_BRANCH=common-android13-5.10-2022-12

Console trace ends up in a OnBootPhase_XXX loop continually incrementing with similar output repeating. Nothing obvious seem to stand out in the trace such as Fatal errors

```
01-17 12:43:14.120  2587  2587 I SystemServiceManager: Starting phase 500
01-17 12:43:14.122  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500
01-17 12:43:14.124  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.security.FileIntegrityService
01-17 12:43:14.125  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.security.FileIntegrityService took to complete: 0ms
01-17 12:43:14.127  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.pm.Installer
01-17 12:43:14.129  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.pm.Installer took to complete: 0ms
01-17 12:43:14.130  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.os.DeviceIdentifiersPolicyService
01-17 12:43:14.132  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.os.DeviceIdentifiersPolicyService took to complete: 0ms
01-17 12:43:14.134  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService$Lifecycle
01-17 12:43:14.161  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService$Lifecycle took to complete: 26ms
01-17 12:43:14.163  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.powerstats.PowerStatsService
01-17 12:43:14.172  2587  2587 E StatsPullAtomCallbackImpl: Failed to start PowerStatsService statsd pullers
```

Eventually the following line in trace gives a hint that it has given up.

```
01-17 12:44:30.645  2160  2791 I keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: Watchdog thread idle -> terminating. Have a great day.
```

What is the usual process to debug Android Init-Loop using Console/Logcat trace output ?

Since we can rebuild the Software Stack, what is the best place in code to add trace to narrow down problem  ?

Could we be missing a bugfix or patch when we fetch sources directly from android source branches android-13.0.0_r18 & kernel branch common-android13-5.10-2022-12 ?

Could there be a fundamental difference between Android-12 and Android-13 which might require update to device spec ?
I have compared device spec of google/cuttlefish between 12 & 13 but did not spot anything.

Any comments/suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I actually came across this through google, as I'm facing a somewhat similar situation.  My system only makes it to OnBootPhase_200 and gets hung.  I'm actually running off an Arm64 based SoC, with Android-12.  I'm able to boot this system on one device, but the exact same image on another one with *very* similar specs gets stuck.  My current thought is that it might be kernel related, as the kernel between devices is not exactly the same.

If you had any success with this, I'd greatly appreciate any tips on how you were able to debug the issue!